# Laravel Cashier and stripe: how to tie subscriptions to resources

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to setup a subscription based service where a company that has a billing account can create a single subscription for each individual venue registered in their company. The idea is that the company owner which uses the user model, has the billable trait and can create a subscription for each venue.  A company can create as many venues as they want, but must pay individually for each venue that they register for their company. The subscription types a venue can have is either monthly, yearly or trial.

I want to attach the subscription to a resource so I know which subscription that venue is for. Company and venue both have separate models and are linked through a has many relationship.

The structure looks like this

```
Company Owner (user model, has billable trait)

     |

Company (model)

     | Venue 1 (model) - Monthly subscription 

     | Venue 2 (model) - Yearly subscription

     | Venue 3 (model) - Yearly subscription

     | etc ...
```

I was thinking of adding the column `venue_id` to the `subscriptions` table that comes with Cashier. I don't know if it's possible to attach multiple venue subscriptions to the same billable user because I don't know if Cashier supports this. If not would it be better to attach the billable trait to the venue model and just bill the venue instead?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: We ended up shifting focus onto some other work. Thanks for all your help though.

Comment: np, you should keep in mind the solution with Cartalyst. I have worked on some projects that I used Cartalyst's stripe library, instead of the Cashier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Cashier still doesn't support multiple subscriptions per entity, nor multi-plan subscriptions either. There has been a talk and a few pull requests to do this in the future versions of the Cashier since Stripe allows that.

https://github.com/laravel/cashier/issues/397

https://github.com/laravel/cashier/pull/398

https://github.com/laravel/cashier/pull/420

Try to use Stripe's official PHP SDK for the API calls.

You could try using Catalyst's package for Stripe, with or without direct integration for Laravel, but you need to build DB models in order to have an overview and bind it to the billable entity.

Or you can use their paid package - Stripe - Billing - Laravel

https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0

https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe-laravel/10.x

https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe-billing-laravel/10.x

If you want to build DB models on your own, you should create at least tables for 
Subscriptions, Plans, and Invoices.

In the subscriptions table, you should have a column for billable entity id, in this case, Company, and venue_id that relates to the Venue that belongs to the company.

Other than that, to have a better figure on how to build the rest of the tables, take a look at the Cashier's Stripe related table structure, and take a look for the *Subscription Object*, *Invoice Object*, etc.  at the Stripe's comprehensive docs for the API:

https://stripe.com/docs/api
https://stripe.com/docs

https://stripe.com/docs/api